# LOG4J :Error in lo4j.xml

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

The error look like below

log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "log4j:configuration".

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 6 and column 75

log4j:WARN Element type "Configuration" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 7 and column 13

log4j:WARN Element type "Appenders" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 10 and column 78

log4j:WARN Element type "RollingRandomAccessFile" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 11 and column 19

log4j:WARN Element type "PatternLayout" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 12 and column 14

log4j:WARN Element type "Pattern" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 14 and column 14

log4j:WARN Element type "Policies" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 15 and column 47

log4j:WARN Element type "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 17 and column 40

log4j:WARN Element type "DefaultRolloverStrategy" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 22 and column 11

log4j:WARN Element type "Loggers" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 24 and column 50

log4j:WARN Element type "asyncRoot" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 25 and column 38

log4j:WARN Element type "AppenderRef" must be declared.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 30 and column 80

log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a  element.

Here is the log4j file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xo9b188Rmt1WtjjA92rnuoIAvVLJCreA

Comment: Converted xml file to properties file working fine now:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've missing the beginning of the configuration.

[Apache Manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: Can you specify which configuration?

Comment: Previously I saw much shorter logfile, without:
`<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">`
But at this moment i think it could be problem with missing attributes from the XSD, or  missing reference to the XSD file. It's in core/src/main/resources ?